# calling shell from emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I have an executable file that can be used from the terminal command line.

`$ foo "bar"`
which returns a single line of text

I would like to be able to call this function while editing files.

I can see that I can do the following

`M-! ~/Library/yolo/bin/foo "bar"`
and I get exactly what I am looking for.

So I am trying to write a function that I can then bind to keys. But I am stumped.

```
(setq foobar-path "~/Library/yolo/bin/foo ")
(defun foo-bar (func)
  (shell-command (concat foobar-path func)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") foo-bar)
```

but I know (emacs is telling me) that I am way way off.

What I would ideally end up with is a keybinding that can send a line of code (like evaluate last expression) to the external function and display the return at the bottom of the screen in the message bar.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

- You need to quote the symbol you pass to `global-set-key`.
- The function has to be a "command".  This is any emacs function marked as interactively callable by containing a top-level `interactive` form.

In particular, if you want to pass in the `func` argument from the minibuffer, you could do this:

```
(setq foobar-path "~/Library/yolo/bin/foo ")
(defun foo-bar (func)
  (interactive "sEnter func: ")
  (shell-command (concat foobar-path func)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'foo-bar)
```

Comment: great! just two questions... if the first char sent to foo-bar is a / the program returns but without a value. is there a way of making the entered string a "string"? so `M-p bar -> "bar". Secondly is there a similar function to interactive that takes a line of text (as in from a file)?

Comment: I think you'd have to quote the string manually.  I don't think there's an alternative to interactive for that and note that you still need interactive with no args to make a function bindable to a key.

Comment: Note that you probably want to be calling `shell-quote-argument` if you're constructing shell commands in elisp.

Comment: I'd recommend not to go through a shell at all, but to run the command directly with `call-process` so you don't need to quote anything.